# to take something in your stride

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "to take stress in your stride" mean ?

> It may be easier to take stress in your stride if you have confidence
>   in yourself and your ability to influence events and persevere through
>   challenges.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/take-sth-in-your-stride

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+in+stride):

> take something in (your) stride

Is an idiom and means:

> to calmly deal with something unpleasant and not let it have a bad effect on you

Eg.

> There's plenty of work to do, but she seems to take it all in her stride. Cooper has learned to take such criticism in stride.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you think if it sounds natural when I say  "I have learned  to take such criticism in  MY stride"  or  should I avoid using "my" if subject is "I"

Comment: @Murat, yes, I think so. As regards the avoiding *my* I don't see any reason.:)

Comment: As an American, I have always heard this idiom used as "take something in stride", never with "your/her/my" added. It's interesting how phrases are used differently in different parts of the country/world. :)